# I need to popup different html pages for different url in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For example if someone is on google.com I need to popup a different page and if someone is on xyz.com I need to pop a different page. Is that possible?

Comment: Put everything in one popup.html and simply toggle visibility of containers depending on the url.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by wOxxOm, it may be a better solution to have a single popup page with several sections, and hide/show them as appropriate.

Start with all hidden, and at runtime make a decision:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    // Note: this requires "activeTab" permission to access the URL
    if(/* condition on tabs[0].url */) {
      /* Adapt UI for condition 1 */
    } else if (/* ... */) {
      /* Adapt UI for condition 2 */
    }
  });
});
```

Do note that it's recommended to use [Page Actions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) instead of Browser Actions for things that make sense only on certain pages.

Answer (score 1):

In your background page you can change the page to display in popup.
Use tabs events to get selected tab and current tab url.

Use :

```
// Update popup url method
var updatePopupURLForSelectedTab = function (selectedTab) {
    var popUpURL = DEFAULT_URL_OF_YOUR_HTML_FILE;
    var selectedTabURL = selectedTab.url;

    if (selectedTabURL.match(/.*\.?google\.com.*/) != null ) {
        popUpURL = GOOGLE_URL_OF_YOUR_HTML_FILE;
    } 
    else if (selectedTabURL.match(/.*\.?xyz\.com.*/) != null) {
        popUpURL = XYZ_URL_OF_YOUR_HTML_FILE;
    }

    // Set Popup URL
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup :popUpURL
    });
};

// Get current selected Tab 
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    updatePopupURLForSelectedTab(tab);
});


// Listen for selected tab
chrome.tabs.onActiveChanged.addListener(function(tabId, selectInfo) {
    // Get selected tab
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function (tab) {
    updatePopupURLForSelectedTab(tab);
    });
});


// Listen navigation update
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    updatePopupURLForSelectedTab(tab);
});

// Listen for window change
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function (windowId) {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(windowId, function (tab) {
        updatePopupURLForSelectedTab(tab);
    });
});
```

Comment: Not enough. Does not catch navigation without changing tabs.

Comment: Add [onHistoryStateUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onHistoryStateUpdated) listener then (and maybe `onCommitted` too).

Comment: `onUpdated` should be okay. Take note also of `onReplaced`. But still, it's a very fragile solution.. The comment to the question has a better idea.